# Removing unwanted characters VBA (excel)

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I want to be able to copy raw data into column A, hit run on the macro and it should remove any unwanted characters both before and after the data that I want to keep resulting in a cell just containing the data that I want. I also want it to go through all cells that are in the column, bearing in mind some cells may be empty.

The data that I want to keep is in this format: `somedata0000` or `somedata000`

Sometimes the cell will contain 'rubbish' both before and after the data that I want to keep i.e. `rubbishsomedata0000` or `somedata0000rubbish` or `rubbishsomedata0000rubbish`.

And also, sometimes a **single** cell will contain:

```
rubbishsomedata0000rubbish
rubbishsomedata0000rubbish
rubbishsomedata0000rubbish
```

This will need to be changed to:

```
NEW CELL: somedata0000
NEW CELL: somedata0000
NEW CELL: somedata0000
```

The 'somedata' text will not change but the 0000 (which could be any 4 numbers) will sometimes be any 3 numbers.

Also there may be some rows in the column that have no useful data; these should be removed/deleted from the sheet.

Finally, some cells will contain the perfect somedata0000, these should stay the same.

```
   Sub Test()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        c = removeData(c.text)
    Next
    End Sub

    Function removeData(ByVal txt As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim allMatches As Object
    Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(somedata-\d{4}|\d{3})"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

    If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        result = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)
    End If

    ExtractSDI = result

    End Function
```

I have put my code that I've got so far, all it does is go through each cell, if it matches it just removes the text that I want to keep as well as the stuff that I want removed! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code

- As Gary said, you Function isn't returning a result
- Your Regex.Pattern doesn't make sense
- Your Sub doesn't attempt to handle multiple matches
- Your Function doesn't even attempt to return multiple matches

---

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With
    For i = rng.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
        result = removeData(rng.Cells(i, 1))
        If IsArray(result) Then
            If UBound(result) = 1 Then
                rng.Cells(i, 1) = result(1)
            Else
                rng.Cells(i, 1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(result) - 1, 1).Insert xlShiftDown
                rng.Cells(i, 1).Resize(UBound(result), 1) = Application.Transpose(result)
            End If
        Else
            rng.Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function removeData(ByVal txt As String) As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim allMatches As Object
    Dim RE As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

    RE.Pattern = "(somedata\d{3,4})"
    RE.Global = True
    RE.IgnoreCase = True
    Set allMatches = RE.Execute(txt)

    If allMatches.Count > 0 Then
        ReDim result(1 To allMatches.Count)
        For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
            result(i + 1) = allMatches.Item(i).Value
        Next
    End If
    removeData = result
End Function
```